# How is Blockchain Ledger implemented/ stored in a peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

In Hyperledger Fabric the ledger consists of two distinct, though related, parts – a “blockchain” and the “state database”, also known as “world state”. The blockchain is immutable whereas the world state data can be modified or deleted.

The world state is physically implemented as a database using CouchDB or LevelDB. If so, how is the immutable blockchain implemented - as plain text, json or any other storage forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's internally stored in each of the peer in a data serialization form called [protocol buffer](https://www.skcript.com/svr/protocol-buffers-may-be-the-next-data-serialization-game-changer/).

If you use the bash access to the peer docker service, you can find them at `/var/hyperledger/production/`.

These can be converted to json format using configtxlator tool

- `configtxlator proto_decode --input fabric_block.pb --type common.Block`

Refer [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/configtxlator.html) for more info.